# Making HTTP requests to other services from CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to make HTTP requests to other web services from CouchDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

If you tell us what you're specifically trying to do (ex., reacting to data you see come into CouchDB), then there might be a easy CouchDB solution for what you're trying to do such as http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html and http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB uses SpiderMonkey as JavaScript engine. If it is possible to make http requests from SpiderMonkey - maybe you can make it from CouchDB.

Comment: No, you can't. Stop answering when you don't know the answer.